# Conditional Formatting Remove the rules but keep the Highlight colors

Tags: excel, vba

I have done my project which using the Condition Formatting to compare with multiple condition.
But I facing a problem which is once I clear the condition, the highlight color can't able to keep it.

I having a button for `Sub Check_Duplicate()` and another button for `Sub Uncheck_Duplicate()`

Here is my Coding

```
Sub Check_Duplicate()

    Range("H8:AK9999").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=ISNA(MATCH(RIGHT(""00000000""&$A8, 8) & ""-"" & RIGHT(""0000"" & H8, 4), 'Shp'!$P$9:$P$65536, 0)) = FALSE"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    
End Sub

Sub Uncheck_Duplicate()

Range("H8:AK9999").FormatConditions.Delete

End Sub
```

[image]

I wish to have keep the Highlight colors. But I not sure how to make it permanent.

Comment: https://ibb.co/PcDTcPn           sample picture